Density of squares using large sieves
I am reading Serre's Lectures on the Mordell-Weil Theorem, where he specifically talks about a Large Sieve inequality and proceeds to give an example.

Theorem. (Section 12.1) Let $K$ be a number field, $\Lambda$ be a free $O_K$ -module of rank $n$. Let $\|\cdot \|$ be a norm over $\Lambda_{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \Lambda$. Fix a subset $Y$ of $\Lambda$. Let $x,Q$ be real numbers such that $x \ge 1, Q>0$. For every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in \Sigma_K$, let $w_p$ be a real number in $[0,1)$. Let $\Sigma_K(Q)$ consist of all $\mathfrak{p} \in \Sigma_K$ such that $N(\mathfrak{p}) \le Q$. Assume

The set $Y$ is contained in a ball of diameter $N$. i.e, there is $a_0$ in $\Lambda_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $|a-a_0|\le x$ for all $a\in Y$.
For every $\mathfrak{p}\in \Sigma_K(Q)$, the image $Y_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of $Y$ in $\Lambda/\mathfrak{p}\Lambda$ by reduction modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ satisfies
$$|Y_{\mathfrak{p}}| \le (1-w_{\mathfrak{p}})|\Lambda/\mathfrak{p}\Lambda|.$$
Then,
$$|Y| \ll_{K,\Lambda, \|\cdot \|}\frac{x^{[K:\mathbb{Q}]n}+Q^{2n}}{L(Q)},$$
where
$$L(Q):=  \sum_{\substack{\mathfrak{a} \subseteq O_K\\
     \text{squarefree}\\
     N(\mathfrak{a}) \le Q}} \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \mid \mathfrak{a}} \frac{w_{\mathfrak{p}}}{1-w_{\mathfrak{p}}}.
  $$



He then gives the easy example by considering $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}$, $n=1$, $x$ a real number, $Y$ to be the set of squares in $[1,x]$, and $w_p$ to be near $1/2$ for every prime $p$. Then, $\sum_{\mathbb{Q}}(Q)$ would consist of primes $p <Q$, and $\Lambda_p$ would be squares in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. As there are $(p-1)/2$ squares in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the assumptions of the Theorem are satisfied. He then claims $|Y| \ll x^{1/2}$. I do not see how this last conclusion follow?

This is actually fairly straightforward, nevermind. As seen here, the number of squarefree numbers upto $Q$ is approximately $6Q/\pi^2$ and so we have $L(Q) \sim Q$ and by taking $Q \sim x^{1/2}$, one gets the answer.
